# EPSG:4326 layer on top of a EPSG:27700 base layer

Tags: geojson, arcgis-js-api, srid

I have a base layer in arcgis for javascript in spatial reference EPSG:27700. I want to overlay a boundary layer which is in the format of a geojson file.

I initially generated the geojson with a crs EPSG:27700 but when attempting to add this layer using the following, the boundary layer does not display:

```
const geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
            url: 'data/boundary.geojson',
            renderer: renderer
        });
map.add(geojsonLayer);
```

Upon doing some digging around on the ersi site it states the GeoJSON data must comply with the RFC 7946 which states that the coordinates are in spatialreference WGS84 which would EPSG:4326 (source https://support.esri.com/en-us/bug/specific-geojson-files-from-the-national-oceanic-and-at-bug-000145783)

Is there any harm overlaying layers in different spatial reference systems (SRID) on top of each other or should i simply create polygon layer using the existing geojson so that all the layers are in the same spatial reference system?

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: This question of if it is any harm in doing so, only depends on the necessary accuracy of your layers. ArcGIS has to do a conversion of either layers to have them correspond to each other. However there can only be slight differences depending on the different SRS and transformation-formulas. If sub-meter accuracy is not crucial, there is no harm in doing so. In fact it is normal practise.